# Jade - span in iteration

Tags: pug

How do I add span when I am itering over a dictionary?

```
  ul(class="nav navbar-nav")
  - var currency = {'Dollar':'0,12', 'Euro':'0,18', 'TL':'0.341', 'SEK':'0,18', 'MEK':'0.341', 'YEN':'0,18', 'NOK':'0.341'}
  - each v, c in currency
      li=c + ": " + v
```

I want the currency which is the "c" to be bold.

This code outputs: Dollar:0,12 Euro:0,18 etc.

I want: **Dollar**:0,12 **Euro**:0,18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough that colon (`:`) turns out to be the tricky part, but there are a few ways you can do this. One is to use [tag interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/), which looks like this: `#[span.my-currency= c]`.

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
  - each v, c in currency
    li #[span.my-currency= c]:#{v}
```

Or you can use JavaScript (`+`) concatenation, like this:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
  - each v, c in currency
    li
      span.my-currency= c
      = ":" + v
```

Or:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
  - each v, c in currency
    li
      span.my-currency= c
      | :
      = v
```

Here they are in a snippet:

```js
var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
var target = document.getElementById('target');

var currency = { Dollar: '0,12', Euro: '0,18', TL: '0.341', SEK: '0,18', MEK: '0.341', YEN: '0,18', NOK: '0.341' };
target.innerHTML = jade.compile(template)({ currency: currency });
```

```css
.my-currency { font-weight: bold; }
pre { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jade/1.11.0/jade.min.js"></script>
<pre id="template">
ul.nav.navbar-nav
  - each v, c in currency
    li #[span.my-currency= c]:#{v}

ul.nav.navbar-nav
  - each v, c in currency
    li
      span.my-currency= c
      = ":" + v

ul.nav.navbar-nav
  - each v, c in currency
    li
      span.my-currency= c
      | :
      = v
</pre>
<div id="target"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- each v, c in currency
    li
        strong= c
        span : #{v}
```

or

```
- each v, c in currency
    li #[strong= c]: #{v}
```